# Need help with my tyres peeling

Tags: ford, tires

My offside front tyre is peeling tread but the other 3 are in very good condition. Why is this happening? All tyres are inflated correctly as well. Do I need an alignment? Thanks.

[image: peeling tyre]

Comment: I see the vote to close. The Meta discussion we had that put "tire health" off-topic focused on the "Is this tire safe?" and "Should I replace it?" questions. This question, on the other hand, addresses the cause of a tire condition. I think this is on-topic, and should be left open,

Comment: I agree with David on this, this question deserves to stay open.

Comment: I agree with @DavidSupportsMonica this should remain open.

Comment: That makes sense, vote withdrawn.

Answer (score 7):

If this is only affecting one front wheel there is something seriously wrong somewhere. I would expect a tracking problem to affect both tires.

Possibly you have bent one of the links in the steering mechanism, or something is worn or broken in the suspension on that side of the car, so the wheel is "pointing in the wrong direction" or its camber is wrong and it is only running on the edge of the tire when you are cornering.

Get some specialist advice (i.e. not from your local tire shop which also does wheel alignment!)

Comment: It could easily be a suspension joint to cause wear like that - just had the inner edge of a rear tire worn off due to a rear suspension bush failure so replacing the rear arms sorted that.

Answer (score 0):

How old are these tires? It is not best to drive a car when the tire tread starts to peel. It is best to visit a car mechanic or have it replaced immediately.